# saving tempfile at step of iteration for saving memory

Tags: python, directory, pickle, subdirectory, temporary-files

im thinking about some way of saving memory

the problem is that i have for each project something like 30 files containing each 45k lines with ~20 parts of data separated to some subparts containing ~100lines

in some code i concat and put subparts to parts in dataframe
then in the end of code that is puting readed and parsed data to dictionary looks like this

```
    d4={}
    V1=data_inputs
    K1=V1.keys()
    for k1 in K1: #k1 is file number
        d3={}
        V2=V1[k1]
        K2=V2.keys()
        for k2 in K2: #k2 is superpart number
            d2={}
            V21=V2[k2]
            K21=V21.keys()
            for k21 in K21: #k21 is part number
                V22=V21[k21]
                K22=V22.keys()
                for k22 in K22: #k22 is part name
                    V23=V22[k22]
                    [...]
                    d1=SOME_PARSING_FUNCTION(...)
                    d2[k21]={k22:d1}
                d3[k2]=d2
        d4[k1]=d3
    return d4
```

so the output has scheme:

```
{k1:{k2:{k21:{k22:pd.DF or pd.Panel or pd.Panel4D}}}}
```

and output of code would be

```
{01:{5:{01:{name1:DF},02:{name2:P},...,15:{name15}},
     8:{01:{name1:DF},02:{name2:P},...,30:{name30}}}
{...}
{30:{5:{01:{name1:DF},02:{name2:P},...,15:{name15}},
     8:{01:{name1:DF},02:{name2:P},...,30:{name30}}}
```

but its only for project 1, and if i get to parse more projects, it consume too much memory i think

**QUESTION:** So is it good idea to write each subdirectory to some tmp file using pickle.dumpy(), and then read it?

Any one has an idea how to do it? i mean, i should put to tmp file each subdirectory of file or whole directory of file?

**QUESTION 2:** how to read later all of these tmp files and put all in one pickled file?

afther code do it all, im writing it to one big raw pickled h5 file, and from there im reading it again and puting into another h5 file but with some scheme like:

```
'/k1/k2/k21/k22/' V22
```

or

```
'/k2/k21/k22/k1/' V22
```

where V22 are some values in form like DataFrame
(and that part of code is much faster in time than making directories)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to concatenate subparts into parts especially when subparts have huge size.
Try to parse each file separately and append results into single output file.
This approach should be faster and also allow you to avoid using tmp files.